# first time trying caching in Rails, don't even know where to begin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching

First time trying to actually implement caching into an app, and I find it really confusing. Even after reading [this indept article](http://www.nateberkopec.com/2015/07/15/the-complete-guide-to-rails-caching.html)
, I am still pretty lost.

I decided to start out simple. In a test app that I'm making, I have the following chunk of API call.

```
def get_champion
        champion_url = "#{BASE_URL}/api/lol/static-data/na/v1.2/champion#{API_KEY}"
        parse_json(champion_url)
    end
```

I think this is the best place for me to cache because the data that is returned from this call is always static.

What is the best method for me to cache here? There are so many caching techniques described in the article, and I don't know which one to really use.

If there is a technique that you think I should try to implement, please let me know, and I'll try my best to implement it.

PS: Right now, the server logs says that

```
Completed 200 OK in 2860ms (Views: 2858.6ms | ActiveRecord: 0.3ms)
```

which is really high, is it now?

Edit: After reading through the rails doc, I am thinking that low-level cache might be appropriate for this scenerio.

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  def competing_price
    Rails.cache.fetch("#{cache_key}/competing_price", expires_in: 12.hours) do
      Competitor::API.find_price(id)
    end
  end
end
```

In the code provided,it is said that the cache_key needs to be generated. How did they generate the cache_key?

Comment: Have you read the documentation? http://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html

Comment: Yeah, I am thinking that low-level cache might be the right method for this case

Comment: cache_key is a method that they made up to build a hashed string based on the model's id and updated_at attributes. That way the hash key is automatically invalidated when the model is updated. See the section 1.3 on Fragment Caching for how they did it.

Answer (score 0):

Low-level caching would work, but I believe this resides in memory, and is not persisted. If you don't want to keep it in memory all the time, the next best thing to do is to write it to the disk and then just serve this cached file whenever that request is made.

To do that, you'll need to add the action_caching gem to your Gemfile (only for Rails 4.0 and later):

```
gem 'actionpack-action_caching'
```

Then add the following to your controller:

```
caches_action :get_champion
```

That's it. Now the first time the request is made, it will conduct the full request and output that to a cache file. Subsequent requests will simply retrieve the cache file.

See https://github.com/rails/actionpack-action_caching for more info.

Comment: I am corrected: Rails.cache may or may not be persisted, depending on your chosen cache store. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html#activesupport-cache-store